# Can't bind to 'ngModelOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-input'

Tags: angular, ionic3

im new in ionic and angular. can someone pls tell me how i can use ngmodel in formgroup so that i can take the data. is there some other way how to do this. i searched some answer in google but i dont really find the answer 
this is my .html

```
<ion-slides #signupSlider>
  <ion-slide>
      <ion-list>
        <form novalidate [formGroup]="slideOneForm">
            <ion-item>
              <ion-label color="white" fixed>First Name:</ion-label>
              <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Enter your First Name" formControlName="fname" [(ngModel)]="userData.fname" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
        </form>
      </ion-list>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
        <ion-list>
            <form novalidate (ngSubmit)="signup()" [formGroup]="slideTwoForm">
                <ion-item>
                  <ion-label color="white" fixed>Address:</ion-label>
                  <ion-textarea placeholder="Enter your Address" rows="3" formControlName="address" [(ngModel)]="userData.address"></ion-textarea>
                </ion-item>
            </form>
        </ion-list>
        <button ion-button round (click)="signup()" [disabled]="slideTwoForm.invalid">Signup</button>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

and this is mt .ts file

```
import { Component,OnInit,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastController,LoadingController  } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } 
from '@angular/forms';

import { AuthServiceProvider } from '../../providers/auth-service/auth- 
service';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';

@Component({
 selector: 'page-signup',
 templateUrl: 'signup.html',
})
export class SignupPage {
 responseData : any;
 slideOneForm: FormGroup;
 slideTwoForm: FormGroup;
 userData = { "fname": "", "address": "" };

@ViewChild('signupSlider') signupSlider: any;

constructor(
 private authService: AuthServiceProvider, 
 public toastCtrl: ToastController,
 public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
}

ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.signupSlider.lockSwipes(true);
}
ngOnInit(){
this.slideOneForm = new FormGroup({
  fname: new FormControl('', [Validators.maxLength(30), Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*'), Validators.required]),
});
this.slideTwoForm = new FormGroup({
  address: new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*'), Validators.required]),
});
}

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue beacause for, you are using formControlName and ngModelOptions together,

if you want to use both on same input then make formControlName as small case,

here's is an changes,

```
<ion-list>
   <form novalidate [formGroup]="slideOneForm">
      <ion-item>
         <ion-label color="white" fixed>First Name:</ion-label>
         <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Enter your First Name" formcontrolName="fname" [(ngModel)]="userData.fname" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </form>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-zegc1e?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) demo

Comment: when i do that theres an error. Template parse errors

Comment: Did you checked stackblitz.? as there i have added FormsModule and ReactiveFormModule in app.module.. might the problem with that also.

Comment: Can't bind to 'ngModelOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-input'.

Comment: i already added formsModule and reactiveformModule in app.module

Comment: ithink ihave some mistake in my codes. your answer is really helpful. thanks man

Comment: very Niceeeeeeeeeeeee

Answer (score 1):

You are suppose to use either formcontrolName or ngModel. In Component, you are creating Reactive Form Control. so please remove ngModel in the template files.

If you want to use ngModelOption, you can remove formControlName. Use either one not both.